# Eclipse IDE showing error for Composite Primary Key classes in JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have an Entity class with composite PK as below:
using @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId annotations.

```
/** The primary key class for the uom_conversion database table. */
@Embeddable
public class UomConversionPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="product_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int productId;

    @Column(name="base_uom_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int baseUomId;

    @Column(name="to_unit_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private int toUnitId;
    //getters, setters
}
```

And the Entity which is using it is:

```
/** The persistent class for the uom_conversion database table. */
@Entity
@Table(name="uom_conversion")
public class UomConversion implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UomConversionPK id;
}
```

Here Eclipse is displaying error: "UomConversionPK cannot be resolved to a type"

[image: Eclipse error snapshot]

In another project I'm using Entities with composite PK without any errors.

Now this seems to be a JPA facet problem, wondering why Eclipse is not able to resolve UomConversionPK or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you importing `com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.UomConversionPK` in your `UonConversion` class?

Comment: Both UomConversion and UomConversionPK classes are in same package. And this error is occurring in other Entity classes as well - having composite PK.

Comment: Are you positive they're in the same package? Eclipse can see your `UomConversionPK` class, but it's not visible from within `UomConversion` without an explicit import, which suggests it's actually in a different package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this error do occur sometimes for `@EmbeddedId` annotation, though not always, when creating JPA entities from tables using JPA Tools.

In my case this problem was not resolved until I set the following to `Ignore` and then back to `Error`: 
`Windows -> Preferences -> Java Persistence -> JPA -> Errors/Warnings -> Attribute -> Embedded ID classes should implement hashcode() and equals()`.
This error occurs even if Embeddable class do have hashcode() and equals() method implementation. May be this works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks, this worked and saved a lot of my time and effort! Seems this to be an eclipse bug.

Comment: BTW, it's under the Type field group for `@IdClass` (not embedded ID)...